# Convergence of $\frac{1}{2^k} \frac{1}{z-w_k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $w_1,w_2,w_3,...$ are points on the unit circle. Consider the infinite series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \frac{1}{z-w_k}$$ Let $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1 \}$

A) Show that series converges for each $z$ in $D$.

B) Show that the sum of the series is an analytic function of $z$ for $z$ in $D$.

**My approach for A**

Since $|w_k|=1$,

$$ \left |\frac{1}{2^k} \frac{1}{z-w_k} \right | \le \frac{1} {1-|z|} $$ which converges by comparison to $\sum |z|^n$ for $|z|<1$

Is this the right approach?

For B, I don't know how to go about it any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Hint: If a sequence of "complex" analytic function converges uniformly in a region $S$ of the complex plane, the limit is also analytic in $S$. For a proof, see answers of this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/368664/59379). The key is  [Morera's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).

Comment: @achillehui I never had this theorem in my course. How would we do it by comparison?

Comment: Let $f_s(z) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{1}{(z-w_k)^s}$ for $s \in \mathbb{N}$. $f_1(z)$ is the limit of your series and it is well defined over $D$ by part $A$. By a similar argument, $f_2(z)$ is well defined over $D$ too. If one differentiate $f_1(z)$ formally term by term, one will get $-f_2(z)$. So what you need to do is prove

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f_1(z+h)-f_1(z)}{h} + f_2(z) = 0$$

which isn't very hard for you specific form of series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_{k,m}(z)=-2^{-k}w_k^{-m-1}z^m$ for $k\geq1, m\geq0$, and $z\in D$.
We have
$\vert A_{k,m}(z)\vert=2^{-k}\vert z\vert^m$, so
$$\sum_{k,m}\vert A_{k,m}(z)\vert=\frac{1}{1-\vert z\vert}.$$
This absolute convergence, (in fact, it is uniform on every compact subset of $D$), allows us to interchange the order of summation as follows:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty A_{k,m}(z)\right)=
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{k,m}(z)\right)
$$
for every $z\in D$. This is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot\frac{1}{z-w_k}=
\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mz^m
$$
with $$ a_m=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{-1}{2^kw_k^{m+1}}.$$
This proves that the function : $\displaystyle f(z)\buildrel{\rm def}\over{=}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}\cdot\frac{1}{z-w_k}$ is analytic in the unit disk $D$ and gives its power series expansion.

Comment: There is a loose end in this proof. One should justify why the radius of convergence of $\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m z^m$ is at least $1$.

Comment: @achillehui A power series that converges for $|z|<1$ must have a radius of convergence (RC) greater or equal to $1$. because the fact that $(|a_m|r^m)_m$ is bounded for every $r\in[0,1)$ implies that $RC\geq1$.

Comment: +1 Oh I see, you are using the fact that LHS converges. This is clever. I was thinking a more explicit justification $|a_m| \le 1$.