# $H^\infty$ with the norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ is a (complex) Banach space

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces

Where can I find the proof of this lemma?

$H^\infty$ with the norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ is a (complex) Banach space

Where $H^\infty = \{f \in H(U) \mid \|f\|_\infty \lt \infty\}$ with $U$ be the open unit disk in the complex plane, and $H(U)$ is the set of holomorphic functions in $U$.

Comment: @Berci Yes, $H(U)$ is the set of holomorphic functions in $U$.

Comment: Being a Cauchy sequence $f_n$ in $H^\infty$ means $\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty\to 0$ as $(m,n)\to (\infty,\infty)$. I guess the proof can go as follows: show that $f_n(z)$ converges pointwise to some $f(z)$ for each $z\in U$, then show that $f\in H(U)$, and finally that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know the proof that $C(X)$ is a Banach space, right?  The completeness comes from the fact that a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.  So do the same thing, except using the fact that [a uniform limit of holomorphic functions is holomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368664/uniform-limit-of-holomorphic-functions).