# prove that every solution of analytic ODE x˙=f(x,t) is analytic

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-functions

i have searched in many books but i did not find a proof for the statement in the title.
 I know its linked with Cauchy's theorem, but i need a full and reasoned proof. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried, and where did you fail?

Comment: i have tried to use the method of majorants to solve the problem but failed.

Answer (score 3):

The Picard iteration in the proof of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem gives you a sequence $(\varphi_i)_{i\geq 0}$ converging in the sup-norm to $x$. However, all the $\varphi_i$ are analytic (prove this by induction, using that $f$ is analytic) and therefore $x$ is analytic as well.

**Added much latter:** A more complete answer about the real-analytic Picard-Lindelöf theorem can be found here [Why does rational dependence of $f'$ on $f$ imply that $f$ is real-analytic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4104888/why-does-rational-dependence-of-f-on-f-imply-that-f-is-real-analytic/4105117#4105117)

Comment: how you conclude that $x$ is analytic as well?

Comment: @MatheusManzatto It is a standard fact, that analyticity is preserved under the supremum norm (try to prove this using the Morera criterion, you can look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368664/uniform-limit-of-holomorphic-functions )

Comment: I'm thinking that the domain was $\mathbb {R} $, sorry

Comment: @MatheusManzatto Analyticity is a local property, i.e. we can check it on a small neighborhood. In fact, the Picard iteration only works in a restricted neighborhood. Please let me know if I have to add more details to make it clear