# Why does rational dependence of second derivatives on lower-order derivatives imply the map is real-analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, analytic-functions, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Suppose $u(x,y),v(x,y)$ are smooth real-valued functions defined on an open connected domain $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, satisfying
$$
(\text{Hess}\, u)_{ij}=\frac{P_i(\cos v, \sin v, v_x,v_y,u_x,u_y)}{Q_j(\cos v, \sin v, v_x,v_y,u_x,u_y)}
$$
and
$$ (\text{Hess}\, v)_{ij}=\frac{\tilde P_i(\cos v, \sin v, v_x,v_y,u_x,u_y)}{\tilde  Q_j(\cos v, \sin v, v_x,v_y,u_x,u_y)},
$$
where $P_i,Q_j,\tilde P_i, \tilde Q_j$ are fixed polynomials, and we assume that the denominators do not vanish on $U$.

How to show that $u,v$ are real-analytic?

The analogous one-dimensional version (ODE) of this problem follows from an analytic version of the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4105117/104576), but here we have a PDE.

Note that we have here a "coupling" between $u,v$; however, I am don't even know how one proves the uncoupled, simpler version given by
$$
(\text{Hess}\, v)_{ij}=\frac{P_i(\cos v, \sin v, v_x,v_y)}{Q_j(\cos v, \sin v, v_x,v_y)}.
$$

If this question is too hard for elementary solution, suitable references would also be appreciated.

---

This is not an "artificial" exercise; this problem arises naturally when studying [divergence-free vector fields whose flow has constant norm](https://mathoverflow.net/a/389718/46290).